# Simulation of a fully differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to simulate a fully differential amplifier using Proteus

I am disappointed with the result.

The output waveform (VoP (shown red in oscilloscope) and VoN (shown blue in oscilloscope) does not have a phase difference of 180 degrees. What could be the reason for that?

I have attached a screenshot of my simulation.

Input applied to inverting terminal:

[image: input Applied to inverting terminal].

- Input = Bipolar " 5sin(theta) (green/yellow in oscilloscope 50Hz AC)"
- R1-R4 = 1K (R5 R6'short curcuited')
- FDA   = LMH6552MA (supply voltage +-12V)
- Vcom  = 0V (GND)

--- EDITED :

As per request I have applied input to the positive terminal.

Input applied to non-inverting terminal:

[image: input Applied to non-inverting terminal]

Comment: What frequency is that?

Comment: @VoltageSpike if I am reading the horizontal resolution right (3.03ms per div) then this is about 50Hz. Strange that the VoN and VoP signals appear to be in phase and have the same magnitude... Unless I am looking at this wrong.

Comment: Freqency is 50Hz.;
And yes. VoN and VoP signal is in phase.. !

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong on this but it looks like you have the signal generator connected to the inverting terminal, which means you are probably seeing a 180 phase shift and and a negative gain, which look like the same thing.

Connect the signal generator to the positive terminal (maybe like this:)
[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6551.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1647980765439&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Flmh6551

Comment: I got same result.. ! no change.. ! VoP and VoN are still not 180 phase apart.. !

Comment: Can you show the new sim in your question?